# Interior of $A=\{(a_n)_{n \geq 1} \in l_1 : |a_n| \leq |\frac{1}{2^n}| \}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $A=\{(a_n)_{n \geq 1} \in l_1 : |a_n| \leq |\frac{1}{2^n}| \}$, where $l_1$ is the space of absolutely summable real sequences. Show that the interior of $A$ is empty in $(l_1,d_1)$.

How to prove that for any $(a_n) \in A$ there is some distance $r>0$ such that
$$(x_n) \in A,~d_1((a_n),(x_n))=\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n-x_n|<r~\Rightarrow x_n=a_n$$

Comment: What is meant by $l_1$? Can you clarify?

Comment: Space of absloutely summable real sequences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B((a_n);\varepsilon)\subset A$, you can construct a $(b_n)$, with $b_n=a_n$ for all $n$ except for one $N$, which you choose considering that $|b_N|> \frac{1}{2^N}$ and $|a_N-b_N|<\varepsilon.$

Comment: One can choose $b_N$ such that $|b_N|>\frac{1}{2^N}$, how to ensure that $|a_N-b_N|<\varepsilon$?

Comment: $b_N=a_N+x$, where $x<\varepsilon$ and $|a_N+x|>1/2^N$. I think it'd be helpful if you draw a line, locate $0,a_N,1/2^N$ and $\varepsilon$ ($N$ big enough).